# Display complete stream of response using Data Writer Stream Sockets, Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

i am working on winRT stream sockets of windows phone 8 at client side.My code is

```
  var streamScoket = new StreamSocket();
        await streamScoket.ConnectAsync(new HostName(txtServer.Text), portNumber.ToString(), SocketProtectionLevel.PlainSocket);

        DataWriter dw = new DataWriter(streamScoket.OutputStream);

        dw.WriteString("Hello");

        await dw.StoreAsync();

        DataReader reader = new DataReader(streamScoket.InputStream);

        reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;

        await reader.LoadAsync(4);

        string data = string.Empty;

        while (reader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0)
        {
            data += reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
        }

        txtConnections.Text = data;
        }
```

At server side when i passing "Hello",I am sending a response of "Good you are receiving a message from server" of this text. But in my "txtconnections" textbox only "Good" text is displayed as i know i have passed "4" in "LoadAsync". If i increase "4" to more value i can display all the content. But as Tcp operates on stream of data how did we know the response stream come to end or how will we continue the looping if we have "4" in the "loadasync". Can some one please help me to find the solution and explain me briefly.. And here "UnconsumedBufferLength" contains "4" and from next onwards it was "0"...

Answer (score 2):

Once you have a StreamSocket open communication is unstructured by default. Meaning, you send and receive a stream of bytes and you as the developer need to make sense of them. If you want to transfer a random length string, go for it, but you'll have to structure the Bluetooth StreamSocket to expect those. Such a structure might look like *|1 byte to signal a version number|1 byte to signal free text transfer start|4 bytes to transfer an int32 of string size in bytes|free text in bytes in specified length|4 bytes for string MD5/SHA1 hash to verify the file's contents|*. It's really up to you what the protocol would look like, but remember that you have to send and receive bytes.

Nokia has [an end-to-end sample](http://projects.developer.nokia.com/nfctalk) of initiating an NFC tap-and-share, opening a StreamSocket and transfering structured messages over that socket. It'll show you how to use NFC, escalate to WiFi/Bluetooth and use a real-world versioned structured message format. Check out Nokia's NFC Talk project [here](http://projects.developer.nokia.com/nfctalk) and [here for the interesting part](http://projects.developer.nokia.com/nfctalk/browser/NFCTalk/Communication.cs).

Answer (score 1):

Since TCP operates on a stream of data, the data stream itself must tell you when the response is complete. This is usually done using length prefixing or delimiters. [I have a blog post describing these different approaches.](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html)

The `DataReader` is not part of TCP; it's a general stream reader and interpreter. It's really just `BitConverter` with a (much) better API. It's only going to read from the stream however many bytes you tell it to. Your code has `LoadAsync` load four bytes from the stream into the reader but never any more, so it makes perfect sense that you get a four-byte string and nothing else.

If you can, change the protocol to use length prefixing. Then it's pretty straightforward to use `DataReader` to first read the length and then read the message. If it's not possible to change the protocol, or if you use delimiters, then you'll need to read in [partial chunks of data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datareader.inputstreamoptions.aspx) until you can detect the end of the message, and then save any leftover data that came through to go on the beginning of the next message.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. here i used reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial in my code which means partial chunks of data right? Then how to detect the end of message?I think the loop should continue with 4 bytes until the end of the message..am i right. How to implement it?

Comment: As I stated in my answer, the data itself must tell you when the response is complete. The link to my blog explains two common approaches.